# Using findbugs plugin in sonarqube for java-8 and java-6

Tags: java-8, sonarqube, findbugs

I need to use FindBugs 3.0 in Sonar qube for project running in Java-8 , the sonar server is shared by projects running java-6. (FindBugs 3.0 requires Java-7 to run) Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 is required to *run* analyses, but you can still analyze Java 6 code with FindBugs 3.0.